# Laravel: Cannot generate migration file with make:migration command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration, file-permissions

I've got an ongoing project and migrations were working fine. But I don't know if something has changed, now `php artisan make:migration my_migration_name` is not generating a migration file and not showing any errors as well.

I've tried running it with `-v` verbosity flag but nothing is printed on terminal. My directory permissions seem to be fine;

[image]

I've also tried running it with `sudo` but I got this error message;

[image]

I've updated composer and tried to remove laravel and reinstall `laravel/framework '5.1'`. But nothing seem to help.:(

If someone has faced this kind of issue and managed to resolve it, help would be really appreciated. Any suggestion how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try this one `php artisan make:model ModelName -m` . `-m` creates migration file.

Comment: do you get any output when writing php artisan make ?

Comment: @BalrajAllam I've already created model and table, when this command was working. I just need to add a column Now.

Comment: @FrankProvost it does not show any output.

Comment: @tahirwaseer  Try running `php artisan` in terminal.This gives you a list of laravel commands, if not then there's a problem with some dependencies.

Comment: @BalrajAllam all artisan commands are available. Any suggestions to check dependency issue?

Comment: @BalrajAllam does php artisan make:controller works? Because if it doesn't then its maybe a permission thing

Comment: @Jessedegans `make:controller` is working fine. Controller file is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working somehow. It was really weird behavior and tried different solutions to get it working. I thought I should list down steps I follow to get it working, for someone who may get into this type of behavior.

Short and quick solution might be to clear all your cached data and application configs.

```
php artisan cache:clear # clear all cached files.
php artisan config:clear # clear application config cache
composer dump-autoload # reload all autoload classes
```

And quit the "TERMINAL" and reopen it, hope it should be working now.

If it still don't work then try following options and repeat above mentioned part;

- Re-install your laravel/framework using composer. I found it while searching for solution
- Check your directory permissions, see if you have write permissions.

Hope! It may help someone.

Comment: Worked for me. Only the first two lines did trick in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Glad! it helped you.