# I can't generate migration file with make:migration command in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.4

This happened to me a couple of months ago. It might have happened in the process of a composer update, but I'm far from sure on that one. I've even updated my project to Laravel 5.3 and it still I can not get make:migration to work through Artisan. No the project it updated to 5.4 and it still do not work.

I've checked out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480576/laravel-cannot-generate-migration-file-with-makemigration-command) and I have the exact same problem. The symptoms were exactly the same, however the OPs solutions did not work for me.

- I get no error or result in the terminal when running make:migrate.
- I can generate any other file through Artisan it seems.
- I tried to create a new model and pass the -m along with it. Didn't work.
- I've checked permissions (and even changed migration folder), but didn't
  help.
- If I create my own migration-file the rest of the process through artisan works fine (migrate, DB-manipulation etc).
- I've tried with different terminals and computers.
- Since project were upgraded and even reinstalled I fear it has
  nothing to do with the deep kernal. However maybe some sort of conflict from the higher level.
- And in the last phase of my quest I tried to figure out what user interacting elements that can possibly effect the make:migration. Nothing worked.

I searched the web without any solution, then I gave up on that project and started to make my own migration files. However I now got some new hope when I saw that other thread.

Comment: Create a new project and run `php artisan migrate` first.

Comment: @Chris I've created a few other projects that works fine. It is just this one that seems to cause me trouble.

Comment: Check your Laravel error log. `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Nothing generates there that gives me a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some troubleshooting I finaly managed to figure out the problem. 
I narrowed it down to have something to do with the *config/app.php-file*.
Seems I in this project had typed in:

'timezone' => '**UTC+2**'

This made creation of migration-files come to a halt without error messages. And it effected *only* the creation of migration-files (at least what I noticed).

I changed it to '**UTC**' and it worked liked a charm again.

**Note:** the 'UTC+2' worked in the application and I never saw any other indications of errors regarding the rest of the app.php-file, or in the application in general.

**Solution:** When I instead used the parameters from [this site](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php) it all worked perfectly again.